# Find all real $x$ and $y$ that satisfy $(x^3+y^3)(x^2+y^2)=2(x+y)=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I need help solving.

> Find positive real numbers $x$ and $y$ that satisfies the equation:
> $$(x^3+y^3)(x^2+y^2)=2(x+y)=2$$

I think that in these type of equations I have try to factor out in one side of the equation and look the prime factorization of the number on the right side; and, after that, divide into cases. But I can't seem to quite do it in this one.

Comment: Prime factorization might be helpful if $x$ and $y$ were supposed to be integers, but not when they are real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously $x+y=1$ and using $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$ we get
$$\begin{align}
&&(x^3+y^3)(x^2+y^2) &&=2 \\
&\iff&(x^2-xy+y^2)(x^2+y^2) &&=2 \\
&\iff&\left((x+y)^2-3xy\right)\;\left((x+y)^2-2xy\right) &&=2 \\
&\iff&(1-3xy)(1-2xy) &&=2
\end{align}$$

Put $xy=t$ we get a quadratic equation in t with solution $t_1 = 1$ and $t_2= -\frac{1}{6}$.
The system $xy=1$ and $x+y=1$ has no solution, while $xy=-\frac{1}{6}$ and $x+y=1$ results in a
quadratic equation $6x^2-6x-1=0$ with gives the final solution
$$x=\frac{3+\sqrt{15}}{6}\; \text {and} \; y=\frac{3-\sqrt{15}}{6}$$ or with x and y exchanged.

Comment: Do you mean $x+y=1$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael - thanks for your hint, I corrected it.

Comment: However, $(3-\sqrt{15})/6$ is not positive.

Comment: @RobertIsrael . So there is NO solution in $positive$ $x,y$. This can be seen before the last step, for if $x,y\ge 0$ and $x+y=1$ then $0\le xy\le 1/4$ so $1/4\le 1-3xy\le 1$ and $1/2\le 1-2xy\le 1$ so $(1-3xy)(1-2xy)<1$.

Comment: My edit was for layout , i.e. for style. BTW you can use \iff for $\iff$. And to insert words in a (double-dollars) display, use \text {words} . You can also use \, and \; and \quad to insert varying amounts of extra space.

Answer (score 2):

Note that with $x, y$ positive and $x+y=1$ you can get $0\lt x^3\lt x^2 \lt x$ and $0\lt y^3\lt y^2\lt y$

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the second equation $2 (x+y) = 2$, we see that $x+y=1$.  Now you might substitute $y = 1-x$ into the other equation and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For positive $x,y$, $(x^3+y^3) < (x+y)^3$ and $(x^2+y^2) < (x+y)^2$, then use the nice property that $x+y=1$.